# Query mongo array to count how many times a specific position appears

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Given this document as it follows:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("569190ca24de1e0ce2dfcd4f"),
    "title" : "Once Upon a Time in the West"
    "countries" : [
        "Italy",
        "USA",
        "Spain"
    ],
```

How can I know how many times does Italy come in first? Thanks!

Comment: Something like `db.collection.count({ 'countries.0': 'Italy' });`

Comment: @Neil Lunn, I saw that post and it's not duplicate, it's different: this query need to count how many times the item appears in specific position of the array. And like Veeram's comment, it can also be achieve like this `db.collection.find({ 'countries.0': 'Italy' }).count();
`

Comment: so, this query needs `count`key word...and the other post doesnt. I think this makes a difference

Comment: It's the same query. Using the notation position as `"countries.0"` is the method for accessing a known position. When a question is marked as a "duplicate", nine times out of ten the question itself remains on the site but just "linked" to the other answer. So the title with "count" would allow people to find it better. But the core answer remains the same. So no need for a separate answer, which is of course exactly the same.